# To clear a line in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d, linegraph

I need to clear the current line graph and replace it with a new line graph, as and when I change the month (The createLineGraph method is called each time I change the month). What happens is that, part (just part) of the previous month's graph  coincides with the new line graph. I'm using CoreGraphics + Quartz2D to create the lines. Anyone know a solution to this grating issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest drawing your lines on separate CALayers, that way you can just hide/remove the CALayers.

Comment: Ahh.. That sounds like..work! :| Is there any other way around this? Like a magic spell? :P Thanks for the help anyways. :) Will try it if I don't find any other solution.

Comment: Try drawing the line again after setting the blend mode to kCGBlendModeClear. This will obliterate anything the line touches on the same context, however.

Comment: The problem has been fixed. It was just a minuscule error. I feel sane again. Thanks anyways Alastair! :D

Comment: Alastair Stuart's method helped me out!